# Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Core_Resources' not found in

Tags: drupal, javascript

```
 if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm' && $form->_id == 1) {


   CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptFile(drupal_get_path('module','custom_water') .'/',
     'custom_water.js');

}
```

When I use the above code as mentioned in the link
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Resource+Reference#ResourceReference-Introduction

Add a Javascript file
PHP
CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptFile('com.example.foo', 'bar.js');

I get an error : **Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Core_Resources' not found in**

I am using drupal 7 with CiviCRM

Comment: I think the error message you're posting got cut off, please finish it?  Also, are you adding this code to a Drupal module or CiviCRM extension?

Comment: @JonG I am adding the code in drupal module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is on drupal module add civicrm_initialize(); method above that line